# easeOutBounce effect is not always applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simply i have a `div` which should be animated when i click on a button and hidden when i click on another button:

```
<div id="popup"></div>
<input type="button" value="show and animate popup" onClick="showWithAnimation()" />
<input type="button" value="hide" onClick="aFunction()" />



<script>           
function showWithAnimation(){    

               console.log('animation called');
               $('#popup') .animate({top:(($(window).height()/2)-($('#popup').outerHeight()/2))-70}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce');
           $('#popup').show();
           }

         function aFunction(){//Hide the div

              $('#popup').hide();

          }
</script>
```

What i noticed, is that the bounce effect is applied on the `div` only for the first time i click on the `show and animate popup`, then when i click on `hide` button and then re-click again on `show and animate popup` button, the `div` is shown, but without `easeOutBounce` effect. may i ask you how to go to solve that? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because when the animation is run, the div is in a certain position on the page...but when you rerun it, the div is already in the target position...so it looks like no animation/effect is happening. It's happening, it's just already where you're trying to animate it to. You need first set the `top` and `left` styles to specific values...maybe the top middle of the window. Then, you call `animate` like you are. This way, whenever you click to show the popup, the popup's position always starts at the same place, and animates/ends at the same place.

So you would need:

```
$("#popup").css({"top": "whatever", "left": "whatever"}).animate("whatever", "whatever", "whatever").show();
```

UPDATE:

When you use `animate`, it literally animates the selected element(s) from its original values to have the properties you pass it. So in your case, you are animating the `top` and `left` styles. By default, the div is positioned somewhere on the page - I think with yours, it's hidden and just somewhere in the middle of your HTML. So technically, it's `top` and `left` are undefined, but are really some finite values, like "200, 250". When you call animate, it gradually changes these from the original (200, 250) to what you specify in the `animate` call. So, after the FIRST `animate` call, you move (animate) the div to the center of the window. Then you allow the popup to be closed (hidden). Every click to open the popup after that, it attempts to move (animate) the div to the center of the window...but it's already there (just hidden). So there "isn't" an animation because it's trying to move the div to the position it's already in. Again, as you've noticed in your testing, it's important to note that this happens only after the first time because the div has already been moved to its target position. If you opened the popup, closed it, resized the window, and then opened the popup again, I'm sure there would be some kind of animation (minimally probably). This is because the dynamic target position of the div you specify in the `animate` call has changed (since the window has resized).

Comment: Thanx for this, it works, though i didn't understand very well your explanation. Could you please re-explain in other way :)

Comment: I updated the answer, I hope it helps explain what's happening. The point is that even though the div is hidden when you close it, it's still in the target position you specify for `animate`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the animation does not occur is because the div is already in it's final destination, so when it attempts to animate to that destination, it simply does not move.

If instead of just hiding the div, you animated it back to its original position, or even just made it jump back to its original position after it is hidden, the bounce in  animation would occur again the way you would like it to.

Also, you will want to show the div before you animate it, not after.

**Some other notes:**

It is typically considered best practice not to use inline code in your HTML file. Instead you would want to use an external file which references ids or classes to apply event handlers. This not only makes you HTML and javascript easier to read and traverse, but allows for easier changes after the fact.

*HTML file*

```
<script src="externaljsfile.js"></script>
<div id="popup"></div>
<input id="showButton" type="button" value="show and animate popup" />
<input id="hideButton" type="button" value="hide" />
```

*JS file*

```
$( document ).ready( function() { // runs code once the DOM has loaded
   var $popup = $( '#popup' );

   $( '#showButton' ).click( function() {
      $popup.show();
      $popup.animate( {
         top: ( ( $( window ).height() / 2 ) - ( $popup.outerHeight() / 2 ) ) - 70
      }, 1000, 'easeOutBounce' );
   } );

   $( '#hideButton' ).click( function() {
      // move back to original position here.
      $popup.hide();
   } );
} );
```